# How to replace value in noscript (wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, replace, default-value

I need to replace value in noscript.
I tried the following code but it doesn't replaces the value.
Would you please let me know how to fix the code?

I tried:

```
jQuery("ls-slot-shortcode_actions a noscript").replaceWith("width=42");
```

Existing Code:

```
<li class="ls-slot-shortcode_actions">
     <a href="https://www.myhome.com">
          <img scr="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png">
          <noscript>
             "<img width="18" height="12" class="ls-flag" src="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png" >"
          </noscript>
     </a>
</li>
```

Thank you.

Comment: try jQuery(".ls-slot-shortcode_actions a noscript img").width("42");

Comment: Hi: thank you for your help Kashif. I tried it and it adds style="width: 42px;", and doesn't change width="18" in img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code does the job:

```js
let selector = $(".ls-slot-shortcode_actions a noscript");
let txt = selector.text();

console.log("before modification:" + txt)

let newtxt = txt.replace(/width=".*?"/, 'width="42"');
selector.text(newtxt);

console.log("after modification:" + selector.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="ls-slot-shortcode_actions">
  <a href="https://www.myhome.com">
    <img scr="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png">
    <noscript>
             "<img width="18" height="12" class="ls-flag" src="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png" >"
          </noscript>
  </a>
</li>
```

I you have more lines, and you want to keep just one, you could do that:

```js
let selector = $(".ls-slot-shortcode_actions a noscript");
let txt = selector.text();

console.log("before modification:" + txt)

let newtxt = txt.replace(/width=".*?"/g, 'width="xx"');
newtxt = newtxt.replace(/width="xx"/, 'width="42"');
newtxt = newtxt.replace(/"<img width=.xx. .+>"/g, "");
selector.text(newtxt);

console.log("after modification:" + selector.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="ls-slot-shortcode_actions">
  <a href="https://www.myhome.com">
    <img scr="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png">
    <noscript>
             "<img width="18" height="12" class="ls-flag" src="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png" >"
             "<img width="18" height="12" class="ls-flag" src="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png" >"
             "<img width="18" height="12" class="ls-flag" src="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png" >"
             "<img width="18" height="12" class="ls-flag" src="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png" >"             
          </noscript>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Frenchy: thank you for your help. It changes the number but also creats duplicates. So, there are 3 lines now =>  "<img width="42" height="12" class="ls-flag" src="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png" >""<img width="18" height="12" class="ls-flag" src="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png" >" "<img width="18" height="12" class="ls-flag" src="https://www.myhome.com/img/cco.png" >". Would you please let me know how to fix this, if possible? Thanks again : )

Comment: its not my code which duplicates the lines..you could see in my snippet .. the console shows before and after the modification.. or you already have the 3 lines, check with my code about console.log.. i have added a code to remove unwanted lines..

Comment: Hi Frenchy: Oh, Wow, thank you a lot for your supportive help. You were a big help, and I learnt a lot from you. Have a nice sunday  Frenchy : )